# Modify timestamp script to affect all google sheets, not just one

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

Can anyone tell me how to modify the following code, so that it affects all sheets, not just 'september-2016'?

```
function onEdit(e) {
    var s = e.source.getActiveSheet();
    var cols = [22, 23, 24]
    if (s.getName() !== "September-2016" || cols.indexOf(e.range.columnStart) == -1) return;
    s.getRange(e.range.rowStart, e.range.columnStart + 8)
        .setValue(new Date());
}
```

Thanks very much, H

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please take the [tour] and checkout [ask].

Comment: Thanks for your input Rubén. Sadly the code didn't work however.:(

Comment: I didn't propose any code yet.

Answer (score 0):

You want to get all sheets and iterate through them.
You probably also want to delete the condition that makes the function return if the sheet name isn't September-2016.

```
function onEdit(e) {
  if (cols.indexOf(e.range.columnStart) == -1) return;
  var sheets = e.source.getSheets();
  sheets.map(function(s) {
     var cols = [22, 23, 24]
     s.getRange(e.range.rowStart, e.range.columnStart + 8).setValue(new Date());
  });
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your input Robin. Sadly the code didn't work :(

Answer (score 0):

If you want to have the onEdit script to work when any sheet is edited, try

```
function onEdit(e) {
var cols = [22, 23, 24];
if (cols.indexOf(e.range.columnStart) == -1) return;
s.getRange(e.range.rowStart, e.range.columnStart + 8).setValue(new Date());
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your input JPV. I tried what you said, but it didn't work. Back to the drawing board!.:(

Comment: What didn't work ? Did you get an error ? Please clarify (and maybe share a copy of your spreadsheet).